# qtcreator DEFINES not recognized

Tags: macros, qt-creator, c-preprocessor

Although I defined my macro in the .pro file, it seems qtcreator isn't taking it into account

```
DEFINES += FINOPTION_LIBRARY_EXPORTS
```

(in the .pro file).

This is the macro...

```
#ifdef FINOPTION_LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define FINOPTION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FINOPTION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

(in the global.h)

and obviously...

```
error: C2491: 'GetCALL' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
error: C2491: 'GetPUT' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

I'm compiling with MSVC13 (the odd thing is that if I set define my macro in the preprocessor inside MSVC IDE, it compiles just fine...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found by random typing (lol)...

```
DEFINES+= FINOPTION_LIBRARY_EXPORTS ="1"
```